# Is there a way to see a list of comments I posted?

Tags: support, comments

Question is in the title. Just looking to see if there is a way to see the comments I posted, not just the comments I'm tagged in. (Responses etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your profile, then to "Activity", and there is a "comments" button - that should show your comments you have left.